# hadoop-config.sh in bin/ and libexec/

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

While setting up hadoop, I found that hadoop-config.sh script is present in two directories, bin/ and libexec/. Both the files are identical. While looking onto scripts, I found that if hadoop-config.sh is present in libexec, then it gets executed. If not then the one under bin/ is called. What's the purpose of keeping the same file in two directories?

Answer (score 0):

In ancient versions of hadoop, hadoop-config.sh was located in bin.  When libexec and sbin were introduced in more modern versions, hadoop-config.sh was kept in the two locations for some releases for backwards compatibility reasons.